# GROUP CONCAT not working for some reason

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-concat

I'm forming a select statement and am getting this error.

> FUNCTION GROUP_CONCAT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing
>   and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

I don't understand this because group concats worked with the code someone gave me that I built my new code from.  Here's how it looks

```
SELECT
`shirts`.`shirt_name`,
`shirts`.`men` AS `main_photo`,
GROUP_CONCAT (`shirt_sizes`.`size_name`) AS `sizes`
FROM
`shirts`
JOIN
`shirts_link` ON `shirts_link`.`shirt_id`=`shirts`.`id`
JOIN
`shirt_sizes` ON `shirt_sizes`.`id`=`shirts_link`.`size_id`
JOIN
`shirt_prices` ON `shirt_prices`.`id`=`shirts_link`.`price_id`
WHERE `men`!=''
GROUP BY
`shirt_prices`.`price_cat`
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: What database are you using?  The syntax looks like MySQL, which supports `group_concat`.

Comment: I know, that's the odd thing because like I said, it worked with the other one I crafted this from, but the MySQL version is 5.1.66.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There must be no space between function name and parenthesis. Change

```
GROUP_CONCAT (`shirt_sizes`.`size_name`) AS `sizes`
```

to

```
GROUP_CONCAT(`shirt_sizes`.`size_name`) AS `sizes`
```